# Custom Caption on WP Nivo Slider

Tags: plugins, slideshow

I'm trying to set the Post Title or Post Content as the caption in my [Nivo Slider](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-nivo-slider/). Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the "title" attribute of the images to be the post title. You can do it like this:

```
title=' . get_post_title() . '
```

You will have to modify the HTML output of the plugin, but it should not be very difficult at all.

Comment: That is part of the solution - I posted the full solution on my website: http://s.gavinr.com/mPEvUd